# React state not updating using immutability helper update function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability, formik

Hi I am using Formik in my component, where a method call used like below

```
addMetadata(values) {
        console.log(values);

        let newState = update(this.state, {
            pro: { $set: values}
        });

        console.log(newState); // this point result print as expected
        this.setState(newState);
        console.log(this.state); // but here state not showing update result
    }
```

where my state looks like

```
this.state = {

  pro: {
     key1: '',
     key2: []
     key3: {}
  }
}
```

but states are not updating, can anyone know why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.setState(newState)` is asynchronous (or at least, it can be). Putting a log statement on the next line will not work, because the state hasn't been set yet.

In the rare cases where you need to know when the setState is done, you can provide a callback as the second argument to setState, which will be called once its complete:

```
this.setState(
  newState, 
  () => { 
    console.log(this.state);
  }
)
```

Comment: Awesome, Thanks I was not aware of that.

Comment: well i have a question about how react update the state. does react wait for the function or life cycle method finish the do the update or something else? i hope you have good explanation for this. thank you.